# Error when installing framework using cocoapod

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, jtapplecalendar

I am currently trying to install JTAppleCalendar framework into my project however I keep getting this error from the command line:

```
[!] The `FinalYearProject1UITests [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-FinalYearProject1-FinalYearProject1UITests/Pods-FinalYearProject1-FinalYearProject1UITests.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `FinalYearProject1UITests [Release]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-FinalYearProject1-FinalYearProject1UITests/Pods-FinalYearProject1-FinalYearProject1UITests.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

I have tried to add the `$(inherited)` flag to the ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES line in my build settings for the entire project. Then I also tried changing the build settings created by cocoa pods. However, none of this seems to be working...